# Reflection parameter missmatch

Tags: c#, reflection

I've looked around on SO and Google on some similar issues, but can't find anyway of solving my problem.

Basically I'm getting a parameter mismatch on this code in one of the classes of my restful API:

Param is a **string** (the name of the method I'm looking to use).

```
var myType = typeof(JaberoDC.JaberoDC.JaberoDC);
        var method = myType
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
            .Single(mi =>mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet) 
            && string.Equals(mi.Name, param, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        var subject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
        var result = method.Invoke(subject, new Object[] {"", conStr, ""}); //error here
```

Although I'm invoking the exact same method as this:

```
DataSet ds = jdc.FETCHvw_WorksiteEntry("", conStr, "");
```

[image]

Any clues?

**EDIT:**

```
public DataSet FETCHvw_WorksiteEntry(string strFilter, string strConn, string strUserName, int lStartRowIndex = 0, int lMaximumRows = 0, string strSortExpression = null);
```

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your previous question ?

Comment: Not a duplicate, a continuation of the issue.

Comment: It would also help if you'd provide a [mcve]. For example, if the method has optional parameters or a parameter array, that could explain everything.

Comment: No optional parameters at all. I thought the provided line from the other class would be somewhat self-explanatory.

Comment: Show us the method definition, that would help.

Comment: Yeah, works fine. Debugging goes all the way from the definition of myType to results, where it drops of and displays the parameter count error. :/

Comment: @FelixK. The class (JDC) is a datacomponent in a referenced .dll so and I can't really get to that ATM.
Suffice to say that it takes three parameters and returns a dataset with no issues in the other class.

Comment: @geostocker Of course, go to definition works also here, you also know that it takes 3 parameters therefore VS can see the definition.

Comment: @FelixK. Had no clue about that. Adding an edit with the method defintion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you calling has 3 optional parameters, you don't need them to specify them when calling them inside your C# code, but you need to when you invoke the method by reflection.

```
var result = method.Invoke(subject, new Object[] {"", conStr, "", 0, 0, null});
```

The reflection ignores optional parameters, if you don't want to specify them build yourself a helper method for such calls and add those parameters automatically to the array.

Comment: Can't honestly believe how small of a misstake that was on my part. Thanks, man! Now comes the more difficult part; to dynamically create class instances that can hold various datakey-values. :P